# How to set IDEA better align parameters passed to some method?

Tags: intellij-idea

I cannot make IDEA perfectly align parameters passed to some method when I break them into new line by `Enter` key.

Here is visually what I need. I have a method like this. 
[image]

When I break parameters into new row each, it looks like this.
[image]

Even trying to align them with `Tab` key does not help. 
[image]

You see how ugly this is, not to say it's not easy to reach such code. And all I want is too look like this:
[image]
(Note: this one I set via `Space` key).

I must have been doing something wrong as I can bet this can be set in IDEA. But where?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Bring up `Settings` panel :

```
Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces (tab)
```

Enable `Align when multiline` option in `Method declaration parameters` and `Method call arguments`

Comment: I just had to check "Align when multiline" in "Method call arguments" section.

Comment: Yes, there are two options, one is for method declaration, the other one is for method call

Comment: Words cannot express how happy this has made me. Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the way suggested by @Rangi Lin, also make sure that your

```
Code Style > Java > Keep When Reformating > Line Breaks
```

in your settings is also checked. Otherwise reformatting your code could realign your method params into a single line.